# FFMPEG compilation without compiler optimization

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm compiling ffmpeg for win32 using Microsoft cl compiler. I need to compile it without any optimization, so added configure --extra-cflags= -Od".

Compilation goes fine, but there are a few places like [this](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/sbrdsp_8c_source.html):

Last 3 ifs.

The code compiles, but doesn't link because calls like ff_sbrdsp_init_arm(s); are not removed by compiler. Of course everything is fine when compiling with optimization. Then compiler removes all if(0)s.

There are several similar places in ffmpeg. Why if(0) is used instead of preprocessor's #if 0?

Is there any hidden trick behind this?

Answer (score 3):

One advantage of `if (0) C;` over the `#if` or `#ifdef` solution is that the code is still type-checked by the compiler. If someone changes the prototype of one of the functions invoked within `C`, the compiler will warn that the callsite needs to be adjusted, even if the person doing the compilation does not use this configuration.

For your practical problem of compiling the code with a compilation platform that does not remove these dead calls, you can safely change them to the preprocessor version(*). However, perhaps you should explain why you must compile without optimizations. Perhaps it would be allowable and possible to enable just the optimization that removes this kind of dead code.

(*) Here I subtly avoided to specifically recommend either `#if ARCH_ARM` or `#ifdef ARCH_ARM`, but this is doing you a disservice. Be aware that they are different. If `ARCH_ARM` is always defined as either `0` or `1`, use `#if ARCH_ARM`. If it is either defined or not, use `#ifdef`. If the macro is intended to work inside `if (…)`, it is the former case.

Comment: Yes, if I only knew how to switch on optimization that removes dead code but does no other optimizations... BTW. I need it to debug - step by step in debuger

Comment: @Kamil_H It would be difficult to handle the substitution automatically, but you can at least use the regexp `if ([A-Z_]*)` to find all the sites likely to need a modification (this finds all the `if` conditions made of only capital letters and underscores).

Comment: OK, thanks for advice, but my question is slightly different: Is there any reason for these ifs. It seems that someone did it on purpose.

Comment: @Kamil_H I don;t see any other reason than, since there are many developers, avoiding that not everyone compiles the same preprocessed source and sees the same warnings. In an environment with little hierarchy and many developers, it would get tiring quickly if others broke your stuff by accident because they don't compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Actual ffmepg design :

```
if (ARCH_ALPHA)
  ff_me_cmp_init_alpha(c, avctx);
if (ARCH_ARM)
  ff_me_cmp_init_arm(c, avctx);
if (ARCH_PPC)
  ff_me_cmp_init_ppc(c, avctx);
if (ARCH_X86)
  ff_me_cmp_init_x86(c, avctx);
if (ARCH_MIPS)
  ff_me_cmp_init_mips(c, avctx);
```

Good simple design :

```
#if USE_INLINE_ASM
  if (ARCH_ALPHA)
    ff_me_cmp_init_alpha(c, avctx);
  if (ARCH_ARM)
    ff_me_cmp_init_arm(c, avctx);
  if (ARCH_PPC)
    ff_me_cmp_init_ppc(c, avctx);
  if (ARCH_X86)
    ff_me_cmp_init_x86(c, avctx);
  if (ARCH_MIPS)
    ff_me_cmp_init_mips(c, avctx);
#endif
```

Good extended design :

```
#if (ARCH_ALPHA)
    ff_me_cmp_init_alpha(c, avctx);
#elif (ARCH_ARM)
    ff_me_cmp_init_arm(c, avctx);
#elif (ARCH_PPC)
    ff_me_cmp_init_ppc(c, avctx);
#elif (ARCH_X86)
    ff_me_cmp_init_x86(c, avctx);
#elif (ARCH_MIPS)
    ff_me_cmp_init_mips(c, avctx);
#endif
```

Why ffmpeg don't use good simple/extended design is a mystery...

If a people define ARCH_ALPHA to 1 and ARCH_ARM to 1 at the same time, it will not make sense, but the code will compile (under VS), with strange behaviour, off course.

Saying that :

> One advantage of if (0) C; over the #if or #ifdef solution is that the
>   code is still type-checked

is just stupid in the case of ffmpeg compilation using VS. If you don't need ALPHA/ARM/PPC/X86/MIPS/..., why compile it ?